# Loading data to datagrid takes too much time

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, asynchronous, datagrid

I have a DataGrid control in my WPF app. It's bound to ObservableCollection of Model objects. Each Model object has a constructor, which applies an EF-Model object as an argument. After app user enters correct credentials, there's a method, which should be executed. This method load's data asynchonously from DB (about 1000 EF-Model objects). After loading I pass each object to Model constructor (smth like `MyEFModelObjectsCollection.ForEach(o => MyObservableCollection.Add(new Model(o)))`). But it takes too long time to load this thousand of objects into my DataGrid. How should I deal with it?

Comment: You could try creating an ObervableCollection and pass in the models in the constructor. And then set this new ObervableCollection as ItemsSource of the DataGrid

Comment: DataGrid is slow.  Can you use ListView / GridView?

Comment: @Frisbee, it seems, you're right. After I added new method to my ObservableCollection (AddRange()), I stiil took too much time to load Data, but after binding my collection to a listview, problem's been solved. Can you explain, why datagrid takes so much time to load data?

Comment: I usually use Elisium.extra nuget package for my  wpf app's interface. And it has pretty good-looking datagrid. I find it very useful, but it't annoying me, cause it's too slow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use ListView / GridView unless you need to edit
If you only need basic editing (Textbox) still use ListView

DataGrid does a lot but it comes with a LOT of overhead
The data model alone is way complex

Answer (score 1):

Possible reason is that the method ObservableCollection.Add() generate event CollectionChanged each time. So it is impact on perfomance of your application.
Furthermore ObserverCollection not contains method AddRange(). But you can add own ObservableCollectionEx:ObservableCollection and implement AddRange(IEnumerable collection) method. You can find many examples how to do it.

Comment: I've implemented AddRange(), but it didn't help. I've also removed asynchronous execution, but it still doesn't work. Since I've changed all of it, I can see ContextDeadlock exception thrown. I'm really frusterated with it.

Answer (score 1):

One good way of achieving a better user experience in this type of scenario is to have a wrapper ViewModel for each row. Create 1000 wrappers and bind your grid to the collection of these new ViewModels. On your DataGrid Columns XAML use the FallBack value in the bindings to show a temporary value. Then when your asynchronous data service returns your Model objects, pass each one into a wrapper ViewModel and update the ViewModel's properties with the new values, so that the grid is allways responsive, and gradually shows the correct data.

Comment: That's pretty interesting. Can you provide a little example or a link?